# send message (String) from file to MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have a file with contains my server that get’s content from a client app. How can I send the content the server receives to my MainActvity? 
if I try MainActivity main = new MainActivity(); in the server file the app crashes.

Server file.

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
                connected_server = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connected_server = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (msg != null){
          //Where I need to send the received content to the main activity 

            Log.e("INPUT", msg);
        }
    }
}


  Main Activity 
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  …
public void  message_recieve(String msg){
   // do stuff with messages 
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a callback, so that you can receive the result correctly when the server request ends